# How can I set unique recurring intervals for sidekiq-scheduler?

Tags: redis, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

I am surprised there isn't more documentation on this, or maybe I am looking in the wrong place. I have set up sidekiq and sidekiq-scheduler in my rails app to handle recurring scheduled tasks. It works like a charm for basic jobs like documented:

`Sidekiq.set_schedule('heartbeat', { 'every' => ['1m'], 'class' => 'HeartbeatWorker' })`

However, I require more unique and dynamic schedules. Something along the lines of:

`Sidekiq.set_schedule('heartbeat', { 'every' => ['1month'], 'class' => 'HeartbeatWorker' })`

or even better:

`Sidekiq.set_schedule('heartbeat', { 'every' => ['first_of_month'], 'class' => 'HeartbeatWorker' })`

Is there a way to handle this complexity with my current setup or do I require another gem?
This is my first time working with sidekiq and cron.

Comment: According to the sidekiq-scheduler documentation, it uses rufus-scheduler for the schedule types.  This appears to be the rufus-scheduler documentation you need: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#first-monday-last-sunday-et-al

Comment: Great. Thanks. Will check this out